# SAML2 with OAUTH

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, passport-saml

I’m currently developing an application in Angular and would like to implement SAML 2 authentication to the front end but want to use OAUTH in my nodejs backend api. Does anyone have an example of how to generate an OAUTH token from SAML.

Using passportjs for OAUTH authentication

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.